# Programar triángulo pascal en PSeint sin el uso de bucles

Tags: algoritmos, pseint

La idea es crear el triangulo de pascal sin utilizar ningún ciclos intente con funciones pero no determino como se retorna en `pseint` esta basado en este que este hecho en `C++` [Triángulo de Pascal](http://cod-ayu.blogspot.com/2015/10/un-programa-que-permita-visualizar-el.html)

A continuación es lo que tengo hecho (sin funcionar):

```
   Funcion llenar_pos <- llenar (fila,indice)
        Definir llenar_pos Como Entero
        Si fila=1 Entonces
            fila <- 1
        SiNo
            Si indice=0 O indice=fila-1 Entonces
                indice <- 1
            SiNo
                llenar_pos <- -1
            FinSi
        FinSi
    FinFuncion

Funcion espacios_en_blanco (n)
    Si (n>0) Entonces
        Escribir ' '
        espacios_en_blanco(n-1)
    SiNo
        Escribir ''
    FinSi
FinFuncion

Funcion mostrar_pascal(pos,fila,n,esp,band)
    Si fila<=n Entonces
        Si band==true Entonces
            espacios_en_blanco(esp)
            band <- false
        FinSi
        Escribir llenar(fila,pos),' '
        Si pos<fila-1 Entonces
            mostrar_pascal(pos+1,fila,n,esp,band)
        SiNo
            Escribir endl
            band <- true
            mostrar_pascal(0,fila+1,n,esp-1,band)
        FinSi
    SiNo
        Escribir endl
        band <- true
    FinSi
FinFuncion

Funcion triangulo_pascal(filas)
    mostrar_pascal(0,1,filas,filas,true)
FinFuncion

Algoritmo sin_titulo
    Escribir 'ingrese filas:'
    Leer filas
    triangulo_pascal(filas)
FinAlgoritmo
```

hasta aqui funciona pero al ingresar el numero de filas que quiero que se genere el triangulo pascal se gerean 0 por el numero de filas de la correcta generacion del triangulo

Answer (score 1):

Tu código tenía algunos errores, propios de una persona que no maneja la sintaxis de PSeInt de ningún perfil.
1) En PseInt las constantes lógicas son Verdadero y Falso y no true y false como en inglés
2) endl no es palabra clave en PSeInt, eso se controla con Sin Bajar 
3) Es conveniente configurar PSeInt para que obligue a declarar los tipos de variables eso ayuda a deteclar mejor los errores.

Acá el programa funcionando

```
Funcion retorno <- llenar_pos (fila,indice)
        Definir retorno Como Entero;
        Si fila=1 Entonces
            retorno <- 1;
        SiNo
            Si indice=0 O indice=fila-1 Entonces
                retorno <- 1;
            SiNo
                retorno <- llenar_pos(fila-1,indice-1)+llenar_pos(fila-1,indice);
            FinSi
        FinSi
    FinFuncion

    Funcion espacios_en_blanco (n)
        Si (n>0) Entonces
            Escribir ' ' Sin Bajar;
            espacios_en_blanco(n-1);
        SiNo
            Escribir '' Sin Bajar;
        FinSi
    FinFuncion

    Funcion mostrar_pascal(pos,fila,n,esp,band)
        Si fila<=n Entonces
            Si band==Verdadero Entonces
                espacios_en_blanco(esp);
                band <- Falso;
            FinSi
            Escribir llenar_pos(fila,pos),' ' Sin Bajar;
            Si pos<fila-1 Entonces
                mostrar_pascal(pos+1,fila,n,esp,band);
            SiNo
                Escribir '';
                band <- Verdadero;
                mostrar_pascal(0,fila+1,n,esp-1,band);
            FinSi
        SiNo
            Escribir '';
            band <- Verdadero;
        FinSi
    FinFuncion

    Funcion triangulo_pascal(filas)
        mostrar_pascal(0,1,filas,filas,Verdadero);
    FinFuncion

    Algoritmo sin_titulo
        Definir filas Como Entero;
        Escribir 'ingrese filas:';
        Leer filas;
        triangulo_pascal(filas);
    FinAlgoritmo
```